# How to calculate the expire date?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to check the expired date of each product before adding it to the and if it is expired, do not add it, but instead, this code just gives me the wrong answer. it just jump  to else

```
conn.Open()
Dim a As date
cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE expdate<=@exp", conn)
a = cmd.Parameters.Add("@exp", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
While dr.Read
    count += count + 1
End While
conn.Close()
If count = 0 Then
  msgBox("the product is good")
Else
    MsgBox("the product expired!")
End If
```

Comment: All you're doing is determining whether there are any expired products in the database. If that's not what you want, why are you doing it? Think about the actual logic involved in what yoiu actually want to achieve, then make your best attempt at implementing that logic in code. You clearly haven't done that or you wouldn't have ended up with code that clearly doesn't implement useful logic.

Comment: First, learn SQL basics, such as `SELECT COUNT(*)`. Second, learn basic code syntax. `count += count + 1` is wrong; it adds `count + count` and then adds `1`, which means every time the number is more than doubled, rather than incremented by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim count As Integer = 0
Using conn As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"), _
       cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblproduct WHERE expdate <= current_timestamp()", conn)

    conn.Open()
    count = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
End Using

If count = 0 Then
    msgBox("the product is good")
Else
    MsgBox("the product expired!")
End If
```

Comment: It brings an error "specified cast is not valid"